# 'Function' object is not subscriptable - Python

Tags: python

I've tried to solve an assignment with this code:

```
array = []
total = 0


student = int(input("How many student in your class: "))
print("\n")

for x in range(student):
    score = int(input("Input score {} : ".format(x+1)))
    while True:
        if 0 <= score <= 100:
            break
        score = int(input("Invalid score!!, please re-enter: "))
    array.append(score)
print("\n")

def grade(score):
    if scores >= 90:
        grade ["A"] += 1
    elif scores >= 80:
        grade ["B"] += 1
    elif scores >= 70:
        grade ["C"] += 1
    elif scores >= 60:
        grade ["D"] += 1
    else:
        grade ["E"] += 1

print("Number of A: ",grade["A"](score))
print("Number of B: ",grade["B"](score))
print("Number of C: ",grade["C"](score))
print("Number of D: ",grade["D"](score))
print("Number of E: ",grade["E"](score))
```

But when I run the code:
How many students: 5

Input score 1: 90
Input score 2: 80
Input score 3: 70
Input score 4: 60
Input score 5: 50

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Testing code.py", line 33, in 
    print("Number of A: ",grade"A")
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

The error is because grade is a function object, and you're not referencing that object correctly. But there's a lot more wrong. Your function grade(score) doesn't return anything. In the function you reference "scores" and not "score." You then reference the function name again, but not as the correct object, you're not doing anything recursive you just have a bad name.

Potentially, what you could do is this:

```
def grade(score, grade_track):
    if scores >= 90:
        grade_track["A"] += 1
    elif scores >= 80:
        grade_track["B"] += 1
    elif scores >= 70:
        grade_track["C"] += 1
    elif scores >= 60:
        grade_track["D"] += 1
    else:
        grade_track["E"] += 1
    return grade_track
```

At some point you'll want to initialize the grade_track dictionary and properly fill it in with your scores (I suggest a for loop).

Comment: display but the value is 0
Number of A:  0
Number of B:  0
Number of C:  0
Number of D:  0
Number of E:  0

Answer (score 0):

Careful how you name things. You're naming your dictionaries the same as your functions, which creates problems. Also be careful of using names such as `scores` when you only defined `score`.

I believe this is more or less what you're trying to do:

```
# a function
def make_grades(scores):

    # a dictionary
    grades = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0, "E":0}

    for score in scores:
        if score >= 90:
            grades["A"] += 1
        elif score >= 80:
            grades["B"] += 1
        elif score >= 70:
            grades["C"] += 1
        elif score >= 60:
            grades["D"] += 1
        else:
            grades["E"] += 1
    return grades

# make a dictionary object using your function
grade = make_grades(array)

# print values in your dictionary
print("Number of A:", grade["A"]))
print("Number of B:", grade["B"]))
print("Number of C:", grade["C"]))
print("Number of D:", grade["D"]))
print("Number of E:", grade["E"]))
```